# Java - array of text fields not displaying

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, textfield

In my GUI class I have an array of textfields, which I initialized in this class constructor. The code is as follows

```
JTextField[] arrayOne= new JTextField [10];
        for(int a = 0;a < 10;a++)
        {
            arrayOne[a] = new JTextField(String.valueOf(0));
            arrayOne[a].setBounds(189 + a * 50, 156, 39, 23);
            arrayOne[a].setVisible(true);

        }
```

The problem is, that when I run my GUI, it does not show these text fields. Why not?

Comment: do you add them to a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `JTextField` in the layout.

You should use `add` method of the container/or the class if you extend JFrame inside the `for`.

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

> **Adding Components to a Container**
>
> When you add components to a panel or content pane, the arguments you
>   specify to the add method depend on the layout manager that the panel
>   or content pane is using. In fact, some layout managers do not even
>   require you to add the component explicitly; for example, GroupLayout.
>   For example, BorderLayout requires that you specify the area to which
>   the component should be added (using one of the constants defined in
>   BorderLayout) using code like this:
>
> pane.add(aComponent, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); The how-to section for
>   each layout manager has details on what, if any, arguments you need to
>   specify to the add method. Some layout managers, such as GridBagLayout
>   and SpringLayout, require elaborate setup procedures. Many layout
>   managers, however, simply place components based on the order they
>   were added to their container.
>
> Swing containers other than JPanel and content panes generally provide
>   API that you should use instead of the add method. For example,
>   instead of adding a component directly to a scroll pane (or, actually,
>   to its viewport), you either specify the component in the JScrollPane
>   constructor or use setViewportView. Because of specialized API like
>   this, you do not need to know which layout manager (if any) many Swing
>   containers use. (For the curious: scroll panes happen to use a layout
>   manager named ScrollPaneLayout.)
>
> For information about how to add components to a specific container,
>   see the how-to page for the container. You can find the component
>   how-to pages using How to Use Various Components.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more case for non visibility.

```
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(1000,1000);//Where f is the JFrame reference
```

Add the above statements after adding the `JTextFields` to the required `Frame`.